# On the derivation of Rindler metric

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to reproduce the derivation of the Rindler metric in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Theory_of_relativity/Rindler_coordinates) but I came at a point which I cannot undertand. In the Rindler coordinates section, $\alpha$ is the proper acceleration and $u$ is the coordinate velocity of the accelerated frame as measured by an inertial observer. The author writes as follows:

> $\cdots$ Having both the position and time now as a function of proper time
> $${\displaystyle ct={\frac {c^{2}}{\alpha }}\sinh \left({\frac {\alpha \tau }{c}}\right)}{\displaystyle}$$
> $${\displaystyle x={\frac {c^{2}}{\alpha }}\cosh \left({\frac {\alpha \tau }{c}}\right)-{\frac {c^{2}}{\alpha }}}$$
> We merely make a natural choice of primed coordinates for which ${\displaystyle x'=0}$ is described by those equations of motion. Rindler's choice was
> $${\displaystyle ct=\left({\frac {c^{2}}{\alpha }}+x'\right)\sinh \left({\frac {\alpha t'}{c}}\right)}$$
> $${\displaystyle x=\left({\frac {c^{2}}{\alpha }}+x'\right)\cosh \left({\frac {\alpha t'}{c}}\right)-{\frac {c^{2}}{\alpha }}}$$
> which does just that.

I didn't found a way to convince myself that this procedure is correct. How can I obtain those transformation?

Comment: Supposing you accept the first two equations as being correct, I think it is quite obvious  that in the primed coordinates the world line satisfying $x'(t')=0\,,$ for all $t'=\tau$ is the same as the world line described by the first two equations. In what sense do you think this proceedure is not correct?

Comment: ($\tau, x'$) are the proper coordinates used by the accelerated observer. So x'=0 will correspond to observer's trajectory in the lab frame ($x,t$). See the derivation in chapter 8 of "Introduction to Quantum Fields in Classical Backgrounds" by Mukhanov, S. Winitzki

Comment: See the derivation https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0601179